# Snowflake Connector installation error in mac

Tags: python-3.x, connector, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

While installation of snowflake connector on mac, I am getting below error:

```
0,>=0.1.10->boto3<1.7.0,>=1.4.4->snowflake-connector-python)
Installing collected packages: pyOpenSSL, future, pycryptodome, ijson, snowflake-connector-python
  Found existing installation: pyOpenSSL 0.13.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (pyOpenSSL) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling pyOpenSSL-0.13.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-k7J_5R-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pyOpenSSL-0.13.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Seems like its already finding packages but when I am trying :

```
import snowflake.connector
```

inside python3 shell, its not working saying "no module found".
any pointers to the solution.

Comment: please formate it correctly

Comment: Thanks @alexander for formatting.

Comment: i am working on following versions :
Mac : 10.12.6 .  
python : 3.6 . 
pip 9.0.1

Comment: is the way of importing it is correct ? did you see the documentation of it ? and did you try `from snowflake import connector` ?
can you give its documentation link ?

Comment: also check this `from snowflake.connector import connect `

Comment: Thanks for the replying. It got resolved using below steps :

1. Make sure ur XCODE version is up-to-date so that you will not get issue related to C compiler.  
2. Use python version 3.6 and pip3 for the snowflake connector . 
3. Use sudo pip3 install snowflake-connector .

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would not recommend to install Snowflake python connector to the system python, because there may have conflict with the existing packages, such as PyOpenSSL. A similar issue is explained here:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector-install.html#pyopenssl-on-mac-os-x

Virtualenv/pyvenv/venv is strongly recommended to isolate the runtime environment.

```
python -m venv myenv
source myenv/bin/activate
pip install -U pip
pip install snowflake-connector-python
```

Comment: Hi Sig,
Thanks for reply. It got solved and I used above mentioned steps to get it going.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a permissions issue to me based on this:

```
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Try to re-install with `sudo pip...`